# iTextSharp Delete column

Tags: vb.net, gridview, itext

I am using iTextSharp to export a gridview to PDF however I have a column that I would like to not include as it contains a hyperlink for the value. In the gridview in my program I replace the hyperlink with the text 'Details' for every row when displayed. The PDF just doesn't need this column. I have tried -

```
    grdResults.Columns.RemoveAt(11)
    grdResults.DataBind()
```

and

```
    grdResults.Columns(11).Visible = False
```

before the

```
    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells.Count)
```

this is the code I am working with

```
   Protected Sub grdResults_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e   As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdResults.RowDataBound
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
            Dim newHyperLink As New HyperLink()
            newHyperLink.Text = "Details"
            newHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Details.aspx" & Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells(11).Text)
            e.Row.Cells(11).Controls.Add(newHyperLink)
        End If
    End Sub

 Protected Sub btnPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPDF.Click

    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells.Count)

    For Each headerCell As TableCell In grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells
        Dim font As New Font()
        font.Color = New BaseColor(grdResults.HeaderStyle.ForeColor)

        Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(headerCell.Text, font))
        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(grdResults.HeaderStyle.BackColor)
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

    Next

    For Each gridViewRow As GridViewRow In grdResults.Rows

        For Each tableCell As TableCell In gridViewRow.Cells
            Dim font As New Font()
            font.Color = New BaseColor(grdResults.RowStyle.ForeColor)

            Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(tableCell.Text, font))
            pdfCell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(grdResults.RowStyle.BackColor)
            pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)
        Next

    Next

    Dim pdfDocument As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
    pdfDocument.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate())
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDocument.Open()
    pdfDocument.Add(pdfTable)
    pdfDocument.Close()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment, filename-results.pdf")
    Response.Write(PdfDocument)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Update - Thank-you for the code suggestions -- using the exclude by index that was posted below I was able to remove the hyperlink however the column was still there and the cell values shifted by one cell. What should have been the start of row two was now the last value in row one and so on. I changed the code to

```
            Idx += 1

            If Idx = 11 Then
                tableCell.Text = "Details"
                'Continue For
            End If
```

It now places the word "Details" in the column for every row however unlike the gridview and its hyperlink this column in the pdf is just taking up space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just exclude it your `For Each` loop. `Continue For` will skip the rest of the current `For` code and move on to the next item in the collection.

```
For Each tableCell As TableCell In gridViewRow.Cells

    ''//Exclude based on ID
    If tableCell.ID = "Your ID" Then
        Continue For
    End If

    ''//Exclude based on header ID
    If tableCell.AssociatedHeaderCellID.Contains("Your Header ID") Then
        Continue For
    End If

    ''//Exclude based on visibility
    If Not tableCell.Visible Then
        Continue For
    End If
Next
```

And if that doesn't work you can just exclude based on index:

```
For Each gridViewRow As GridViewRow In grdResults.Rows
    ''//Reset the counter on each inner for
    Dim Idx = -1
    For Each tableCell As TableCell In gridViewRow.Cells
        //Increment our counter
        Idx += 1

        ''//Exclude based on index
        If Idx = 11 Then
            Continue For
        End If
    Next

Next
```

Comment: I used the code to exclude based on index and it did remove the hyperlink values in that cell however, it did not remove the column itself. Now it shifted the remaining values over by one. The next row value begins in the cell that was the hyperlink..